# Error at /contact/ -- [Errno 111] Connection refused (in the djangobook , chapter 7: Forms)

Tags: python, django

I get this error while I was learning Django from examples in djangobook (chapter 7 - Forms).

```
Full error:
error at /contact/

[Errno 111] Connection refused

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/contact/
Django Version:     1.8.4
Exception Type:     error
Exception Value:    

[Errno 111] Connection refused

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py in create_connection, line 571
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
```

Here is the code:

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            send_mail(
                cd['subject'],
                cd['message'],
                cd.get('email', 'noreply@example.com'),
                ['siteowner@example.com'],
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Please resolve this error. Thanks.

Comment: The code above isn't the cause of the error, you need to show the full traceback. Note that the Django book is extremely out of date, see [the warning](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html) on the homepage.

Comment: thanks Alasdair, I solved the error by adding  EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend' in the settings.py file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to send email with either no email server running, or without configuring Django to point to it.

If you're just testing locally, the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#configuring-email-for-development) has a few suggestions.

---

You can run

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

And then configure Django's EMAIL_HOST setting to "localhost" and EMAIL_PORT to "1025"

```
# in your settings.py
EMAIL_HOST = "localhost"
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

---

Or set your EMAIL_BACKEND setting to

```
# in your settings.py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

to see any generated emails output to your console.

Comment: tks Oli so much, i added EMAIL_BACKEND it worked, but in my email box, i didn't receive any new mail :( ??